# JPA retrieving collection, avoiding Cartesian product

Tags: hibernate, jpa

HI I have an entity that contains multiple collection fields (Sets).
All collections are annotated with:

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
```

and

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

When trying to retrieve an entity using following JPA query:

```
select o from Organization as o left join fetch o.members left join fetch o.book  left join fetch o.accounts  left join fetch o.events  left join fetch o.parameters where o.id=?1
```

It generates SQL that is a Cartesian product of all the collection which ends up with millions of results.

I thought to retrieve the entity without the collections, but I get exception that it could not initialize Lazy collection.

What is the best practice to retrieve the entity with all collection avoiding Cartesian product?

Comment: Do you use spring, if so please use entity graph http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.0.M1/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph

Comment: Using fetch joins on element collections (one-to-many) is a red alert. Don't do this. It may fail in its entirely in certain situations though your approach may work for a finite number entity associations (collection-valued). Break tasks into separate queries instead. Fetch joins are especially useful for many-to-one single-valued associations.

Comment: @sky_light : Entity graph is a portion of the JPA 2.1 standard which JPA providers have to provide / implement anyway and has nothing to do with Spring which is also available without using Spring.

Comment: Thanks @Tiny, for the clarification.

Comment: Using entity graph still generate cartesian product SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use `Criteria` API so that the `DISTINCT` is not added to the generated SQL. Assuming you are fetching by unique `id`, the method `uniqueResult()` would not fail.

```
public Organization fetchOrganization() {
    Session session = getEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Organization.class, "o")
        .setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
        .createAlias("o.members", "members", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("o.id", id));
    return criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

Comment: Adding DISTINCT on millions of rows take almost 20 min.

Comment: This is not JPA Criteria, and the OP states using JPA. Also you can achieve exactly the same in JPQL as you can in Criteria

Answer (score 0):

You can get just one organizationEntity by the ID and then

```
Hibernate.initialize(organizationEntity) to fetch all lazy collections.
```

Comment: so not very "JPA" then

Comment: Not JPA but tag hibernate exists

Answer (score 0):

NamedQueries with parameters did the job for me....

When you try with

`entityManager.find(PoDetail.class, poNumber)`

you will have all the lists declared in the entities with `@OneToMany` initialized with Cartesian product no of times, which will have duplicates as well. Of course one can eliminate these duplicates by using `Set` but Set does not preserve the order of data insertion and when tried to display in View we have scrambled rows.

I solved this by using :

**NamedQueries with parameters** to avoid such fetching of Cartesian product of collections.

Doing so your view data will be as is with the persistent data insertion order.

Here is the sample code:

Parent Entity class: (It has more list fields, I am mentioning one here)

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="PO_DETAILS")
    @NamedQuery(name="PoDetail.findByPoNumber", query="SELECT p FROM PoDetail p where p.poNumber=:poNumber")
        public class PoDetail implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="PO_NUMBER", unique=true, nullable=false, length=30)
    private String poNumber;

    @Column(name="ACTION_TAKEN", length=2000)
    private String actionTaken;

    .....

    //bi-directional one-to-many association to PcrDetail

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="poDetail", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<PcrDetail> pcrDetails;
```

Child Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PCR_DETAILS")
public class PcrDetail implements Serializable {

@Id
    @Column(name="PCR_NUMBER", unique=true, nullable=false, length=30)
    private String pcrNumber;

    @Column(name="CONTRACT_ID", length=30)
    private String contractId;
    .....

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to PoDetail

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_PO_NUMBER", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private PoDetail poDetail;
```

JPA DAO class:

```
    public PoBean getPoDetails(PoBean poBean) {

    PoDetail poDetail = poBean.getPoDetail();
    String poNumber = poDetail.getPoNumber();
    entityManagerFactory = JpaUtil.getEntityManagerFactory();
    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    try {

        try {

            poDetail = (PoDetail) entityManager
                    .createNamedQuery("PoDetail.findByPoNumber")
                    .setParameter("poNumber", poNumber).getSingleResult();

        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
            poBean.setStatusCode(PopVO.ERROR);
            poBean.setErrorMessage("No PO details foun with PO Number : "
                    + poNumber);
        }

        return poBean;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        poBean.setStatusCode(PopVO.ERROR);
        poBean.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());

        return poBean;

    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```